# How to copy mysql database file to your project folder?

Tags: mysql, database, project

Hi Friends I'm new to mysql but i know how to create user,database, table etc.

Earlier i use to work with ms access as backend. In ms access i had .*mdb file which i can put in my project folder and give it to anybody, so that the user can use my application without worrying about database.

but in MySQL i don't know how to copy database file and put in my project folder so that i can give it to other. and they can use my application without any worries......

plz help.... tell me if i'm wrong in my concept.....

Thanks in advance :))

Comment: If you want a database that fits in a single file without running an actual server, look into SQLite instead of MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion... so you saying that there is no way that mysql provide some files of the database so that it can be export with myproject, so that there is no need of mysql in others pc.

Answer (score 0):

You use `mysqldump` to dump the structure and contents of the database into a file, and then give that to the other person to load into their database server.

Comment: okay.... but i was thinking if mysql provides any database file of the database we want to  use.. like in Ms access they provide .mdb file.

Comment: It uses multiple files, but there's no guarantee that they will be compatible with their setup.